# Nodejs push unwanted duplicated records

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, push

Hi and thanks in advance

I am a student trying to learn nodejs but I got some problem when using push in async function I got some duplicated records with the same ID in my mongodb

[duplicated data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsRGE.png)

your can find below the used code (I did try to use promise.all but unsuccessfully )

```
module.exports.commentPost = async (req, res) => {
  //if (!ObjectID.isValid(req.params.id))
  const check_post = await PostModel.exists({ _id: req.params.id });
  if (!check_post)
    return res.status(400).send("ID unknown : " + req.params.id);

  try {
    return PostModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {
        $push: {
          comment: {
            commenterId: req.body.commenterId,
            commenterPseudo: req.body.commenterPseudo,
            text: req.body.text,
            timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
          },
        },
      },
      { new: true },
      (err, docs) => {
        if (!err) return res.send(docs);
        else return res.status(400).send(err);
      },
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Don't mix and match `await` with the `(err, docs) => ` callback syntax.

Comment: sorry I just added await to check the behavior, it's not present really in the code

Answer (score 1):

Use `$addToSet` as it would only add the item to the given field if it does not already exist. Therefore no duplicates would be added.

```js
try {
    return PostModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {
        $addToSet: {
          comment: {
            commenterId: req.body.commenterId,
            commenterPseudo: req.body.commenterPseudo,
            text: req.body.text,
            timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
          },
        },
      },
      { new: true },
      (err, docs) => {
        if (!err) return res.send(docs);
        else return res.status(400).send(err);
      },
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(err);
  }
```

Comment: I did think to use it but if a user want to add a same comment it will not be possible

Comment: A user can add the same comment as long as the timestamp is different.